# How to add multiple labels in same row and databinding in list view in xamarin.forms?

Tags: listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a list of dictionary like this

```
 List<Dictionary<string, string>> jobList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        jobList.Add(
            new Dictionary<string, string> {

                    { "date","3/12/2018 2:26 PM - 2:56 PM" },
                    { "task_id","15588"},
                    { "task_type","Break Fix"},
                    { "task_status","Accepted"},
                    { "address","Salesforce2 123 Elm St, Vancouver"}

            }
       );

        jobList.Add(
            new Dictionary<string, string> {

                    { "date","3/20/2018 9:23 aM - 10:08 AM" },
                    { "task_id","15589"},
                    { "task_type","Break Fix"},
                    { "task_status","Accepted"},
                    { "address","ABC Chemicals 3 Main Street, Birmingham"}

            }
       );
```

I want to populate these values in a same row as separate labels in a list view.
And number of key value pairs of each dictionary can be different and the order of elements are not constant. Time to time it will be different.
I want to know can I still use setBinding() for this?
If so how to do it with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view), which will be a layout that can hold sub-views like `StackLayout`, `GridView` and etc. It should have at least one [BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) to which you should bind your dynamic data. Then simply add sub-views in a dynamic manner to the root layout. Last, you will have to use the custom control as a [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating) in the `ListView`.